# Some of All Parts

Tags: knowledge, connect-wall, movies

The 16 movie and TV roles below can be grouped into 4 groups of 4, with each group related by a common theme.  In addition, the 4 themes are themselves related to each other by a common theme: one particular entertainment related aspect.

**Can you identify the 4 groups and their themes, and then identify the overall theme?**

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex Murphy | Austin Powers | Bruce Banner | Data |
| Dory | Elena Gilbert | Elliot Alderson | Gandalf |
| Jack Sparrow | Jason Bourne | Jon Snow | Norman Bates |
| Phil | Phoebe Buffay | Spock | Tyler Durden |

For reference, these are the movies and TV series these characters are from ("movies" means "movie series"):

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Robocop (movie) | Austin Powers (movies) | The Incredible Hulk / Avengers (movies) | Star Trek: The Next Generation (TV) |
| Finding Nemo / Finding Dory (movies) | The Vampire Diaries (TV) | Mr. Robot (TV) | Lord of the Rings (movies) |
| Pirates of the Caribbean (movies) | The Bourne Identity (movies) | Game of Thrones (TV) | Psycho (movie) |
| The Hangover (movies) | Friends (TV) | Star Trek (movies) | Fight Club (movie) |

Note: you will need some knowledge about the characters and plots of these movies/shows to solve this puzzle, but once you start guessing the themes it should be possible to quickly classify the unknowns with some minor research.

Hints:

> Try recapping or paring each show: down to its main premise that makes it different from other shows.  Two of the groups can be found this way: the groups with Dory and Tyler Durden.  What are Dory's and Tyler Durden's unique characteristics?
>
>  There are also 3 hidden clues in this puzzle.

New Hint:

> The overall theme is 3 words which are the 3 hidden clues in the puzzle.  You could add "Overused" in front of those three words as well.  If you aren't familiar with "overused ____ _____ ______", look it up online and you will understand the 4 themes a bit better.

Comment: is movie/TV important?  eg. Spock was in the original Star Trek  tv series, and Bruce banner in "The Imcredible Hulk" TV series?

Comment: @Jasen Importance: Spock: yes, Bruce Banner: no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set 1 :

> Dory: Vague Memories (of Parents)
>  Jason Bourne: Vague Memories (of Past life)
>  Alex Murphy: Vague Memories (of Past Incarnation)
>  Phil: Vague Memories (of Bachelor Party)

Theme :

> Amnesia / Memory loss

Set 2 :

> Elliot Alderson: Split Personality + suffers from social anxiety disorder, clinical depression, delusions and paranoia
>  Norman Bates: Split Personality + suffers from schizophrenia and narcissistic personality disorder
>  Tyler Durden: Split Personality + suffers from delusions
>  Bruce Banner: Split Personality (of HULK)

Theme :

> Split Personality / Psychological Disorders

Set 3 :

> Jack Sparrow: Resurrected after escaping the locker
>  Spock: Spock was resurrected through a dangerous procedure
>  Gandalf:  Gandalf the Grey resurrected as Gandalf the White
>  Jon Snow: Resurrected by Melisandre

[[thanks to contribution by @ Morris]]

Theme :

> Resurrection / Return from the Dead

Set 4 :

> Austin Powers: Nigel Powers reveals Austin Powers & Dr Evil Douglas Powers are twins
>  Data: Data has Evil twin Lore
>  Elena Gilbert: Elena Gilbert has Evil twin Katherine Pierce
>  Phoebe Buffay: Phoebe Buffay has Evil twin Ursula Buffay

[[thanks to contribution by @ racraman & @ Morris]]

Theme :

> Doppelganger / Evil Twin Role

Overall Theme Analysis :

> Amnesia / Memory loss
>  Split Personality / Psychological Disorders
>  Resurrection / Return from the Dead
>  Doppelganger / Evil Twin Role
>  ....

HIDDEN CLUE 1 :

> Try recapping or paring each show == TROPES

HIDDEN CLUE 2 :

> Some of All Parts == SOAP

[[thanks to contribution by @ Stiv]]

HIDDEN CLUE 3 :

> one particular entertainment related aspect == OPERA

[[thanks to contribution by @ Stiv]]

Overall Theme :

> OVERUSED
>  SOAP
>  OPERA
>  TROPES

Comment: @JS1 , thanks , I have incorporated your comment into my updated answer .... I hope I am making Progress ....

Comment: JS1 said that in my set 3 2/4 is correct, and you changed only one.

Comment: @Morris , thanks , I have corrected that ! Scrolling Up and Down the Web-Page & the Text Box, & shuffling 16 items is a bit Difficult !

Comment: 4 themes are nearly correct, although I was going for something a little more specific with the 4th one.  Elena Gilbert, Alex Murphy, Jon Snow are not in the right groups.  As for the final theme, try to find the 3 hidden clues, hint rot13 (Npebfgvp).  That will lead you to what the actual 4 themes are (search for it online if you don't know what they are).

Comment: @JS1 , updated the answer : by shuffling those 3 & using new words for some themes ....

Comment: FYI, the hidden hints spell rot13(FBNC BCREN - F B N C sebz gur gvgyr, B C R E N sebz 'bar cnegvphyne ragregnvazrag eryngrq nfcrpg') - this should maybe help you focus a search for a character who satisfies all 4 groups...

Comment: @JS1 , I hope it is complete now, with my final edit ....

Comment: Rot13(Gurzr 4 vf fhccbfrq gb or "rivy gjvaf/qbccrytnatref". Nhfgva Cbjref' gjva Qbhtynf Cbjref vf xabja nf Qe. Rivy, Ryran Tvyoreg'f qbccrytnatre/gjva vf Xngurevar Cvrepr (abg Nyrk Tvyoreg) jub vf na rivy inzcver, Yber vf Qngn'f rivy gjva, naq Hefhyn vf Cubror'f rivy gjva (fur qbrf rivy guvatf gb Cubror).  Gurzr 3 vf fhccbfrq gb or "Ergheavat sebz gur qrnq" juvpu vf fvzvyne rabhtu gb "Erfheerpgvba" rkprcg vg pna or guebhtu nal zrnaf, jvgu gur zbfg snzbhf fbnc rknzcyr orvat Obool Rjvat sebz Qnyynf orvat xvyyrq juvpu gurl yngre jebgr bss nf gur jubyr frnfba orvat n qernz.)

Answer (score 1):

Set 1 [contribution by Prem]

> Memory loss:
> Dory
> Jason Bourne
> Alex Murphy
> Phil

Set 2 [contribution by Prem]

> Split Personality:
> Elliot Alderson
> Norman Bates
> Tyler Durden
> Bruce Banner

Set 3

> Back from the dead:
> Jack Sparrow
> Spock
> Gandalf
> Jon Snow

Set 4

> Evil Twin:
> Austin Powers
> Data
> Elena Gilbert
> Phoebe Buffay

Overall theme:

> One actor/actress plays different characters

Comment: Theme is correct, 2/4 roles correct: there may be more than 4 that fit the theme.

Comment: Rot13: Qngn nyfb unq n gjva yber

Comment: 4th theme essentially correct (2/3 roles correct).  If you guess the overall theme, you can figure out what I was going for instead.

Comment: See my hint for the other answer, you are close as well.

Comment: FYI, the hidden hints spell rot13(FBNC BCREN - F B N C sebz gur gvgyr, B C R E N sebz 'bar cnegvphyne ragregnvazrag eryngrq nfcrpg') - this should maybe help you focus a search for a character who satisfies all 4 groups...